# Meteor.loginWithPassword() gives undefined

Tags: meteor, authentication

I'm currently working on a project to make a Pinterest clone in Meteor. The users need to fill in three test when they create an account, so I need to make a custom registration/login system. For now, I can create a new account, but when I want to log in with Meteor.loginWithPassword() nothing happens. Even no error or result.

Here's my code:

```
'submit .login-form': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var emailVar = event.target.loginEmail.value;
    var passwordVar = event.target.loginPassword.value;

    console.log('here') // This is shown in the console
    console.log(Meteor.loginWithPassword()) // gives undefined

    Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar, passwordVar, function(err, suc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err); // This isn't shown in the console
        } else {
            console.log(succ); // This isn't shown in the console

            Bert.alert({
                title: "Welkom: " + Meteor.user().profile.name,
                message: 'You're logged in!',
                type: 'success',
                style: 'growl-top-right',
                icon: 'fa-check'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Edit:

As asked here's is the user in Meteor.users:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wim1L.png)

And here are the strings that are filled in: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ktR6.png)

Comment: What does your `emailVar` and `passwordVar` say? P.S. `Meteor.loginWithPassword` (without the brackets) should not be `undefined`, the function doesn't return anything when ran, that's why it's `undefined`.

Comment: EmailVar and passwordVar are the strings that are filled in by the user. So there email address and password.

Comment: As the docs say: `Callback: Called with no arguments on success, or with a single Error argument on failure.`

Comment: @MasterAM Yah, that's right. But when I click on the submit button, the user won't log in. After I clicked the submit button I try to get the userId in the console with Meteor.userId(). That gives null

Comment: First, remove ` console.log(Meteor.loginWithPassword()) // gives undefined`. It is redundant. Try to log the email and password and see if they are what you expect.

Comment: @MasterAM I already did, as you say so. It gives the correct email and password combination

Comment: For clarity's sake, please just `console.log` the variables and add them to your question.

Comment: Run `Meteor.loginWithPassword()` with hard-coded string values, does it work then? If so, work backwards.

Comment: @d4nyll I've added two images to the question. The first is the user in the Mongodb and the second is the output of console.log("emailVar", emailVar, "passwordVar", passwordVar)

Comment: Have you added accounts-password? console.log(Meteor.loginWithPassword) should return a function?

Comment: @Vijay This is what I get:

console.log(Meteor.loginWithPassword)
-------
(selector, password, callback) { // 24
    if (typeof selector === 'string') if (selector.indexOf('@') === -1) selector = { username: selector };else se…
-------
undefined

Comment: console.log(succ) is the problem. succ is undefined. So, stops execution after it. try with console.log(suc);

Comment: @Vijay I deleted console.log(succ), but it still doesn't work. So that's not the problem.

Comment: What is Bert? Is it imported. console.log(Bert.alert) to check if defined.

Comment: @Vijay Bert is a package that creates a nice notification in the top. So that's not the problem. Unfortunately.

Comment: How do you conclude that it is not working? There should be some message in console that indicates it is not working. Is it possible to put a breakpoint in the success error handler? Or do a Meteor.user() in console to check if login is successful.

Comment: Not sure where you're at with it right now, but this is simple debugging man...1) Remove everything and slowly add stuff back in to isolate what doesn't work, this might include other code outside of the section in the question 2) `console.log` everything to see what is not as expected

Comment: i have same issue.. i dont know how to make it work at all.. 2 days trying to make the Meteor.loginWithPassword to be exposed.. in client and server.. same errror.. i added the module.. he is in the folder.. but is never imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
'submit .login-form': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var emailVar = event.target.loginEmail.value;
        var passwordVar = event.target.loginPassword.value;

        Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar, passwordVar, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("User logged in");

                Bert.alert({
                    title: "Welkom: " + Meteor.user().profile.name,
                    message: "You're logged in !",
                    type: 'success',
                    style: 'growl-top-right',
                    icon: 'fa-check'
                });
            } else{
                // Do something on error....
                console.log("Not logged in, and error occurred:", err);  // Outputs error
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this isn't working for me. I know this is the right way to code it, but it still doesn't work.